# Lasso regression test MSE lower than train MSE

Tags: regression, predictive-models, lasso, mse, train-test-split

Im currently using Lasso to build a predictive model for numeric variable .
Before scaling the features I split the data for train test and validation . I have a feature named 'year' and i wanted the data to be split in a way that each value of 'year' will  be in train test and validation ( Im dropping the 'year' feature later in the code as I converted it to a dummy variable and Im using the original column of 'year' only for making sure that for the split every dataset has every value of year):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report


train_dfs, test_dfs,validation_dfs = [], [],[]

# Unique years in the 'year' column
unique_years = df_encoded['year'].unique()

# Iterate through each unique year fo  the train test split
for year in unique_years:
    # Extract data for the current year
    year_data = df_encoded[df_encoded['year'] == year]

    # Split the data for the current year
    train_data, test_data = train_test_split(year_data, test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
    test_data, validation_data = train_test_split(test_data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
    # Append to the lists
    train_dfs.append(train_data)
    test_dfs.append(test_data)
    validation_dfs.append(validation_data)
#stratified sampling for validation

# Concatenate the dataframes for the final train and test sets
train_df = pd.concat(train_dfs)
test_df = pd.concat(test_dfs)
valid_df=pd.concat(validation_dfs)
train_df=train_df.drop(columns=['year'])
test_df=test_df.drop(columns=['year'])
valid_df=valid_df.drop(columns=['year'])
X_train, y_train = train_df.drop(columns=['childbor']), train_df['childbor']
X_test, y_test = test_df.drop(columns=['childbor']), test_df['childbor']
X_valid,y_valid=valid_df.drop(columns=['childbor']), valid_df['childbor']
```

After that I  used StandardScaler()

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# Create an instance of standart sacaler
scaler =StandardScaler()

# Fit the scaler on the training data and transform the training data
train_X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

# Transform the test and validation data using the scaler fitted on the training data
test_X_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
validation_X_scaled = scaler.transform(X_valid)
```

Then I wanted to find the best regularization parameter for my model so I used this code :

```
alphas = np.logspace(-2, 2, 300)
errors_coefs = []
error_train=[]
error_test=[]
coefs = []

for a in alphas:
    clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=a,fit_intercept=True)
    clf.fit(train_X_scaled, y_train)
    coefs.append(clf.coef_)
    pred = clf.predict(validation_X_scaled)
    pred_train=clf.predict(train_X_scaled)
    pred_test=clf.predict(test_X_scaled)
    errors_coefs.append(mean_squared_error(pred, y_valid))
    error_train.append(mean_squared_error(pred_train,y_train))
    error_test.append(mean_squared_error(pred_test,y_test))
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(alphas, coefs)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.xlabel("alpha")
plt.ylabel("Coefficients")
plt.title("Lasso Coefficients as a Function of Regularization")
#plt.xlim(plt.xlim()[::-1])  # Reverse axis
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and I got this plot

[image]

And I was wondering how could that be that for small values of alpha the test MSE is lower than train MSE / or equal to it ?Could it be that for lower values of alpha it is capable to "learn" the noise and there for preform better in the test ?